# Create several variables and pass them to script

Tags: bash, variables, send

hope you can help me out on this one, I am fairly new to bash, so I search and find a lot of examples on which I work on but I am a bit stuck here.

I have 2 scripts.

script1.sh one works fine: it downloads the rss feed of a youtube playlist containing title, artist and url of tracks, downloads these items and store them into playlist.txt.

The thing is, I have other youtube playlists and if I want to use a different rss feed page, I need to manually change the url of the playlist in script1.sh.

So I am writing script2.sh that will download the url with all the different playlists rss feeds and then send them one after the other to script1.sh.

The playlist urls are something like that:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/**hashtag_playlist**?&max-results=50&fields=entry%28title,link%29&prettyprint=true

So far I have managed on script2.sh to gather the names and hashtags of my 5 playlists in a playlists.txt like this:

- "playlist1"  PLYNrAD9Jn2WDWZFp23G3a2tkOBtdeNAbc6
- "playlist2"  PLYNrAD9Jn2WCf54CoS22kn3pBX1XUFinE

I also managed to create one text file per playlist and named them from the playlist's name.
What I want to do now is send one hashtag after the other each to script1.sh and make it output the urls, title and artist of each playlist in each adequate file. I need to make each one of the lines, in playlists.txt, a variable and pass them into the url of script1.sh but dont really understand how to do that.

I hope I am clear. I can answer any of your question to clarify something I missed.

Thank you in advance

EDIT: I just started writing bash so I am really shit, these must seem really ugly to you. Sorry in advance :)

script1.sh

```
url="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLYNrAD9Jn2WDmpu3gNVxIVO8bAiOcQkx7?&max-results=50&fields=entry%28title,link%29&prettyprint=true"

name="SlickSlickSound"
```

download url rss feed page to utube

```
wget -O $HOME/Music/"Youtube Playlist"/utube $url 2>&1
```

extract titles from the downloaded page into temp0 
use xml_grep in xml-twig-tools

```
xml_grep 'title' utube --text_only > temp0
```

extract urls to temp2

```
grep -o 'href=['"'"'"][^"'"'"']*&amp;feature=youtube_gdata' utube  > temp
```

strip urls to bare minimum for clarity: www.example.com

```
sed "s/href='http\?:\/\///" temp > temp1
sed "s/&amp;feature=youtube_gdata//" temp1 > temp2
```

merge URL and Title temp files in same file output.txt

```
paste temp2 temp0 > output.txt
```

script2.sh

```
url="http://www.youtube.com/user/SterylMreep/videos?flow=grid&view=1"
```

download page source with all playlists infos

```
wget -O "$HOME/Music/Youtube Playlist"/Playlists/collection $url 2>&1
```

extract name of playlists

```
grep -o 'data-context-item-title=......................' collection > tmp0
```

strip urls to bare minimum for clarity

```
sed 's/data-context-item-title=//' tmp0 > tmp2
sed 's/" d...*$/"/' tmp2 > tmp3
```

Remove spaces and \

```
sed 's/^[ \t]*//' tmp3 > tmp4
sed 's/\///' tmp4 > tmp5
```

extract playlists ID to tmp

```
grep -o 'href="/playlist?list=..................................' collection  > tmp
```

strip urls to bare minimum for clarity

```
sed 's/href="\/playlist?list=//' tmp > tmp1
```

create file with names of playlists and hashtags

```
paste tmp4 tmp1 > playlists.txt
```

Create files with playlist names

```
cat tmp4 | xargs touch
```

What comes next here for passing hashtags in playlists.txt into script1.sh and get titles, artists and urls

Comment: Show us the juicy code you got thus far and point out a problem. That way we can help you, rather than do your coding for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
while read line
do
  sh script1.sh $line
done < script2.sh
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Question though. Once it is done, I want to only run script2.sh. It will take care of calling script1.sh on its own. Will you answer work as well?

Comment: Sure. For example you could save the data in a temporary file (tmp_file) and script2.sh could be like: `while read line; do sh script1.sh $line; done < tmp_file`.

Comment: Thanks! But what I dont understand is I have two items in tmp_file, the name and the hashtag, how can I attribute one different variable to each. Like $name and $line

Comment: I see you asked it in [Send 2 parameters to a script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591229/send-2-parameters-to-a-script)