# Send 2 parameters to a script

Tags: bash, variables, send

I just started using bash so I hope the answer is not obvious.
I have a file called playlists.txt that looks like this:

- ChilledDubstep   PLYNrAD9Jn2WDwRrS_Uw6UR55K-c_s6EH4
- Classical    PLYNrAD9Jn2WDWZFpIG3a2tkOBtdeNAbc6
- ChilledOut   PLYNrAD9Jn2WCfrUCoS22kn3pBX1XUFinE
- SlickSlickSound  PLYNrAD9Jn2WDmpu3gNVxIVO8bAiOcQkx7
- Albums,concerts  PLYNrAD9Jn2WD3BI8o5VjmSbhZgfYh5zaX

I want to assign the first string of each line to $name and the second string to $hash, then send it to script.sh and do this recursively for every line, knowing that the number of lines might increase in the future.

I wrote this but it does not work:
using this ->[How to split one string into multiple variables in bash shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520623/how-to-split-one-string-into-multiple-variables-in-bash-shell)

```
while read name hash
do

        sh script.sh "$name" "$hash"

done < playlists.txt
```

Whats should I be doing instead?
Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Thanks guys, so I changed it to this, it is easier to read. I thought, it was going to resolve my errors, but there are still there...damn it.
So basically, in script.sh, here is the first part:

```
cd ~/Music/Youtube\ Playlist/Playlists/$name

mv $HOME/Music/Youtube\ Playlist/Playlists/$name/TextRecords/lastoutput.txt $HOME/Music/Youtube\ Playlist/Playlists/lastoutput.txt
```

However, the shell returns the error:

```
mv: cannot stat `/home/kabaka/Music/Youtube Playlist/Playlists//TextRecords/lastoutput.txt': No such file or directory
```

That means that where there should the name of a playlist, there is nothing. Do you have any idea why? Is it because $name in my current script and $name in the script above are not the same? Notice that I have the same thing happening for $hash, which should appear in an url but is just blank

Comment: See @DigitalRoss's solution below. For reference, the reason your code doesn't work is because you read a variable called `line` but try to split a variable called `STR`. `name=${line% *} hash=${line#* }` would have done it.

Comment: You should open a new question rather than continuously modify an existing question.

Answer (score 1):

It's close to working, just say `read name hash` instead of `read line`

```
while read name hash; do
    sh script.sh "$name" "$hash"
done < playlists.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you look at my other problem that I edited on the first post please?

Comment: Possibly, the problem there is that your parameters are in `$1` and `$2`. They won't be in `$name` unless you assigned it. The script is run by a different shell and it doesn't know anything about the calling script's variables. If you made the contents of `script.sh` a *shell function*, then it would know about your variables.

Comment: Oh great thats it! Thank you very much!! I sortof merged the two scripts in the same file, and everything is perfect! Would you recommend a website for all these stupid things that seem so simple, its usually never explained, unless you go ask someone?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the output of the echo command as an input file using the pipe,
2. the flag '-d' defines a delimiter for the 'cut' command.

Here's the code:

```
while read line
do
    name=`echo $line|cut -f1 -d' '`
    hash=`echo $line|cut -f2 -d' '`
    sh script.sh $name $hash

done < playlists.txt
```

To your 2nd question: Before moving a file to a directory make sure it exists. You can create it with 'mkdir -p' as follows:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/Music/Youtube\ Playlist/Playlists/lastoutput.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

You're almost there, and there several ways to do this, but a typical solution is

```
while read name hash
do
     sh script.sh $name $hash 
done < playlists.txt
```

IHTH